# Send PHP form data to a different page

Tags: php, forms

I have just written this code in which I have a form. You have to write your name, surname and country. You also have to choose your favourite colour. After that, you push a submit button so that you can see the data afterwards. I'm using the GET method with 1 page, but I have to use a second one with the POST method so that each echo is on that second page.
How could I do that? My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Form</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <section>
 <?php
 if (isset($_GET["name"])){
     $name = $_GET["name"];
     if ($name != ""){
         $surname = $_GET["surname"];
         $country = $_GET["country"];
         $colour = $_GET["colour"];

         echo "<p>";
         echo "<h2>Data</h2>";
         echo $name . " " . $surname . "</br />";
         echo $country . "<br />";
         echo $colour;
         echo "</p>";
     }else 
         echo "<strong>Complete the blank spaces</strong>";
 }else{
 ?>
 <h1>Form</h1>
 <form class="elegant" method="GET" action="?">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Favourite colour</legend>

 <div>
 <label for="nombre">Name</label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"
id="name" />
 </div>
 <div>
 <label for="surname">Surname</label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" name="surname"
id="surname" size="50" />
 </div>
 <div>
 <label for="country">Country</label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Country" name="country" id="country"
size="10" maxlength="9" />
 </div>
 <div>
<select name="colour" id="colour">
<option value="yellow" <?php if ($colour == "yellow" ) echo "selected"  ?> >yellow</option>
<option value="red" <?php if ($colour == "red" ) echo "selected"  ?> >red</option>
 </div>

 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Save" />
 </fieldset>
 </form>
 <?php
 }
 ?>

 </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

I know i have to use a link to that second page, but that's all I know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the code you show is for Page 1 where the user can:

1. Input data if data don't exist;
2. View data and confirm them if they exist. At this point store data in SESSION and send the user to an other page.

To do so, remember you have to add the session_start() command right at the beginning of every page in which you will be able to manipulate Session Data.

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_GET["name"])){

     $name = $_GET["name"];
     if ($name != ""){
         $surname = $_GET["surname"];
         $country = $_GET["country"];
         $colour = $_GET["colour"];

         echo "<p>";
         echo "<h2>Data</h2>";
         echo $name . " " . $surname . "</br />";
         echo $country . "<br />";
         echo $colour;
         echo "</p>";

         $_SESSION["name"] = $name;
         $_SESSION["surname"] = $surname;
         $_SESSION["country"] = $country;
         $_SESSION["colour"] = $colour;

         <a href="another_page.php">Confirm</a>

     }else 
         echo "<strong>Complete the blank spaces</strong>";
 }else{
 ?>
...
```

In "another_page.php" then you will find that you can access your data simply querying the $_SESSION array.

```
<?php
session_start();
...
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Name is " . $_SESSION["name"] . ".<br>";
echo "Surname is " . $_SESSION["surname"] . ".";
// etc.
?>
```

Complete reference is the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and simple reference is in [W3C PHP Sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) page.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, that's what I need to do! But there is something I still don't understand, it isn't working yet. I forgot to say I should use sessions because my teacher told me to, but I don't understand how since he didn't explain it. Anyway, the code you have written seems not to work for me :(

Comment: It works smoothly for me...
Please note that there was a typo in the original code: a missing semicolon after the row `echo"</form>"`.  Maybe you checked it before my edit.
Regarding Sessions: it's all another world, so you have to be more specific.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed it! And yes, I forgot to say I had to use sessions, sorry! What I have to do is the same I said on my first post but using sessions: I have to store the data the form receives in sessions and then send them to the second page via sessions. Do you know how should I do it then? I'm really lost here :(

Comment: I edited my answer adding session management. Consider editing your question for the benefit of community users and for clarity. Note that this arguments deserve at least a reading of the PHP manual if you want to correctly manage them.
Please upvote my answer if it finally satisfies you. ;-)

Comment: That's a really good answer! Thank you! Upvoting it right now :D

Answer (score 0):

In the form tag you can specify where to form gets submitted to:

```
<form class="elegant" method="GET" action="YOUR_PAGE_URL_HERE">
```

Comment: That's right! But there are more things I still don't know :(

Answer (score 0):

On that second page you get the values via the $_GET Variable like

```
<?php
echo $_GET['name'].' '.$_GET['surname'];
```

Comment: That's right! But there are more things I still don't know, it won't work yet :(